# Is this statistically significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, p-value, notation

F value 42.341
P value 1.6E-07
F c.v 3.554

The p-value is more than 0.05 but the F value is significant. Or is the p-value considered small since it has E?

Comment: The `-7` in `1.6E-07` means to move the decimal point seven places to the left. So your P-value is tiny, indicating a highly significant effect. Can't tell the critical for the test without knowing the numerator and denominator DF.

Comment: instead of just showing a p-value, can you give more background, i.e how this result was obtained, and where is output is from?

Answer (score 3):

1.6E-07 denotes 1.6*10<sup>-7</sup> which means 0.00000016. Thus, the p-value is less than 0.05 and you can reject the null hypothesis.